# activating virtual environment using cmd but can't find the interpreter

Tags: python, bash, pycharm

working on pyCharm, I'm activating a virtual environment using git bash, but when I want to select that specific interpreter for my python file. I can't find it in the list or may find it but still invalid.
I'm sure the venv is activated and I don't want to use the base interpreter

- what is the approach? starting a virtual environment using pycharm?.. or hardcoded? in my case using git bash

  edit: I've added the interpreter into my interpreter's list somehow and installed some libraries- when I try to import then I get an error stating that the module isn't found

Answer (score 0):

- Check the bottom right corner. There you can find the options for interpreter setting. In setting by "show all" interpreters would show you all the list.
- There you can also find the git tracker.
- In general, if you can not find something, Right top corner you can see the search icon where you can search what you are looking and you will be directed there.